# Conflict in my ehCache

Tags: spring, ehcache

I am in a Spring environement, using EhCache.
I have 2 methods:

```
@Override
@Cacheable("myCache")
public int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

@Override
@Cacheable("myCache")
public int sub(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

The problem is that when the second method is called with the same argument as the first, the result from the first method is returned!

```
Assert.assertEquals(4, testService.add(2, 2));
Assert.assertEquals(0, testService.sub(2, 2));
```

Returns:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<0> but was:<4>
```

Is there something I did not understand about caching?

Comment: Why do both methods have the same cache name (extrapolationCache)? Are you calling the second method straight after the first? Both methods have the same cache name defined so would use the same cache

Comment: dont change your question completely. It difficult to track if someone else want to give you answers. Add updates in your question. Now my answer is completely different from your question.

Comment: I use the same cache name just because I have lot of method cached, and didn't want to have to define one cache per method
But it looks like it's the wrong approach :)
I was sure the cache was using the method name. I think returning the result of another method because they have the same arguments is a bit silly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both functions are having same parameters and sharing the same `cache` instance `key`.So, it is working as expected when you pass the same arguments. Spring default key generator does not include method name. To solve this either change the `cache key` or overload your method by changing parameters.

```
@Override
@Cacheable("myCache", key="{ #root.methodName, #a, #b }")
public int add(Integer a, Integer b) {
 return a + b;
}

@Override
@Cacheable("myCache",key="{ #root.methodName, #a, #b }")
public int sub(Integer a, Integer b) {
 return a - b;
}
```

You can also create your own cache key generator if you want more customisation.

Comment: Sorry I changed my exemple to make it simpler.

So if I understand it well, either I add some parameters, or a need to create 1 cache per method?
Isn't there a way to make the cache look at the method name?

Answer (score 0):

After reading other people answers, I think I can answer my own question.
Let me klnow if I'm wrong.

The solution here is the take the method name as the key:

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "myCache", key = "#root.method.name")
public int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

@Override
@Cacheable(value = "myCache", key = "#root.method.name")
public int sub(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

EDIT:

Ok this is totally wrong as now it does not look at the arguments at all!

```
Assert.assertEquals(4, testService.add(2, 2));
Assert.assertEquals(0, testService.sub(2, 2));
Assert.assertEquals(5, testService.add(2, 3));
```

returned:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<5> but was:<4>
```